# What is the benefit of a male output connector on a powersupply?

Tags: power-supply, design, safety, short-circuit, plug

I saw several power supplies which use a **male output connector**. For example the [Meanwell OWA 90E](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=owa-90e) series uses a `XLR 4P` or `NEUTRIK NC4MX` with 2 pins for `+` and 2 pins for `-`.

[image: XLR 4P]

Source: [Jmb at English Wikipedia (CC-by)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Group_of_XLR_connectors_PICT6918.jpg)

I do not understand why anyone wants to use a plug where pins could be touched and short circuit accidentally. The device itself would not take any damage (short protection: hiccup mode.)

I would **expect female contacts** which can **not** be **touched** or **shorted** easily.

**What feature is worth the risk of accidental contacts on the output?**

Comment: 12 V and short circuit protected. What do you think will happen if you touch it?

Comment: All of those have at least one contact *shrouded*.  Is the usage of XLR connectors ideal?  Maybe not.  Is it chosen to be compatible with existing equipment where the chassis side is usually female?  Most likely.

Comment: They're very uncommon for all the reasons you stated. There must be some niche product where this configuration is preferable. One situation that comes to mind: the male side could be more prone to damage than the female side; and the power supply is easier to replace than the product. Or perhaps the receiving connector on the product will be continuously powered, so the power supply pins are actually the safer of the 2 to expose? Like you said the power supply is short protected so it's not too risky to leave the pins exposed.

Comment: it is unclear what danger you are perceiving

Comment: @winny 12 V are not safe per se, if the out put is not limited safely (PELV/SELV).

Comment: I fail to see the danger.

Comment: @winny a cheap standard 12V PSU, may have 100V on the output. A SELV/PELV PSU which is connected to mains (CAT II) have to withstand for example 4kV surge without exceeding a save output level. Read about EN 61558-2-6, EN 60204-1, DIN VDE 0100-410 if you are interested in this topic.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I do not understand what you want to say with the rating

Comment: The NEUTRIK NC4MX connector is rated for a voltage <50V and 10A/contact.  They have UL certification as use for data, signal, control and power applications.  **may have 100V on the output**  Now 50V is less than 100V, so I fail to see the danger.

Comment: Quite. The output is protected but that doesn't make accidental shorts harmless. Not accidental shorts in place before the PSU's switched on, they're OK. It's accidental shorts across the exposed male pins when the PSU's already on, such as probing screwdriver, dropped screw/wire during production, servicing or development. Those shorts dissipate power in those pins and you get damaged pins and microwelds. Using female connectors takes the risk of this kind of short from very low/very unlikely to miniscule/impossible so it's the sensible choice. Wonder why they didn't...usually a cost saving.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the danger is that the contacts are exposed. Typical dangers with exposed contacts are electric shock, burns, fire. The connector does not limit the voltage.

Comment: I fail to see how this powersupply would ever output 100 V. Perhaps 500 mV overshoot if you go from max loaf to no load.

Comment: You have to plug it in somewhere.  Main use: cable to cable.  And anything is dangerous if used incorrectly, but <50V DC is considered safe for hand tools, which is the UL rating.